# A smart constructor for an iterator with a reference to a closure inside

Tags: rust, lifetime

Consider the following code for a (greatly simplified) iterator with a reference to a closure inside:

```
struct IteratorState<'a, T: 'a + Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    closure: &'a T,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a + Fn(i32) -> i32> Iterator for IteratorState<'a, T> {
    type Item = i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        None
    }
}
```

It compiles and I can construct `IteratorState`s directly. However, I also need a smart constructor to hide some details of the implementation (not shown in the MCVE). The following attempt does not compile:

```
fn mk_iter<'a, T: Fn(i32) -> i32>(closure: &'a T) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> {
    IteratorState { closure }
}
```

[The error is](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e7ee66ea6ffc6b5e2825c6470d1ab15b&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     IteratorState { closure }
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 13:1...
  --> src/lib.rs:13:1
   |
13 | fn mk_iter<'a, T: Fn(i32) -> i32>(closure: &'a T) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:14:21
   |
14 |     IteratorState { closure }
   |                     ^^^^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that return value is valid for the call
  --> src/lib.rs:13:54
   |
13 | fn mk_iter<'a, T: Fn(i32) -> i32>(closure: &'a T) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> {
   |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I think I understand what the problem is: there's no guarantee that constructed `IteratorState` won't outlive the contained reference (please correct me if I got this wrong), but I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `impl Trait` syntax supports adding lifetimes to the return type:

```
fn mk_iter<'a, T: Fn(i32) -> i32>(closure: &'a T) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> + 'a {
      //                                                                  here ^^^^
    IteratorState {
        closure
    }
}
```

([link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a0161edfac731f4a091a4033a82aae65&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

Comment: Fair enough.  I just worry about the "Rust is black magic" belief that sometimes gets around.